# Make ant output show colours from sub-task output in bash console

Tags: bash, ant

I have an ant build that runs gcc. When run in isolation gcc outputs bash colour codes to enhance the output, making it far more readable than monochrome text.

These colour codes are getting lost as the output passes through ant; I have tried running ant with `-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger`, but that just *controls* the colours, it doesn't pass through codes from the task.

Is there any other logger or option that can enable this facility? If not, I could create a custom logger, but I don't understand why a colour code byte sequence doesn't work when it's passed through ant; what would a custom logger have to do differently to allow them to work?

Comment: To whoever gave an off-topic close vote: _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."_ from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Just try: write a class in Java, use `ProcessBuilder` to start a gcc process, read the output and directly print them to the STDOUT, to see if the colors remains. I guess the color info will lost during this redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed that the loss of colouring was caused by `gcc`, since it will only output colours when `stderr` is a terminal. Since ant reads gcc output via a pipe, the colouring became suppressed.

Fix is to pass `-fdiagnostics-color=always` to `gcc`.